# Query WITH clause error

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query produced a "relation temptable does not exist" error. Your help in figuring out how to make the WITH clause work would be great.  We're running postgresql 8.0.2.  Thanks!

```
WITH tempTable AS (
    SELECT AVG(subtotal_price) AS AverageValue
    FROM orders
)

SELECT subtotal_price
FROM orders
WHERE orders.subtotal_price > tempTable.AverageValue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a subquery on the CTE to obtain the average value:

```
WITH tempTable AS
(
    SELECT AVG(subtotal_price) AS AverageValue
    FROM orders
)

SELECT subtotal_price
FROM orders
WHERE subtotal_price > (SELECT AverageValue FROM tempTable);
```

But, here is another way of doing this using `AVG` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT subtotal_price
FROM
(
    SELECT subtotal_price, AVG(subtotal_price) OVER () AverageValue
    FROM orders
) t
WHERE subtotal_price > AverageValue;
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, both queries work great!  Using AVG as an analytic function is faster than CTE.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A CTE behaves just like a table or view in a query.  You need to reference it in a `FROM` clause:

```
WITH tempTable AS (
      SELECT avg(subtotal_price) as AverageValue
      FROM orders
     )
SELECT subtotal_price
FROM orders
WHERE orders.subtotal_price > (SELECT tt.AverageValue FROM tempTable tt);
```